# Where's per-project TargetPlatformVersion?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution with a Windows Phone 8 C# project and a Windows Phone 8 C++ library. I've moved it to a different computer. Now, when I try to open the solution, the library project fails to load with the following message in the console:

```
MyLib.vcxproj : error  : Unable to read the project file "MyLib.vcxproj".  
MyLib.vcxproj(620,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v7.0\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsPhone.7.0.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

When I look into the project file, I find the following on line 620:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v$(TargetPlatformVersion)\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsPhone.$(TargetPlatformVersion).targets" />
```

So it looks like the value of environment variable `TargetPlatformVersion` is somehow off.

Then I've created another solution on this machine, also C#/C++ combo. That one opens and compiles and runs, nae problemo. Looking at the project file in the newly created library, it has an identical `<Import>` line near the end.

Now, the solution copying might have been not perfect. I did not copy all files - just what I thought were the relevant ones - the .sln, the .vcxproj., but not the .sdf and not the .suo.

It looks like something was missing - a file that defined the value of `TargetPlatformVersion` on solution or project level was not copied, and now Visual Studio is picking a wrong default. Needless to say, WP7.0 has nothing to do with it, it's all WP8.

Any idea where could this setting reside? There's no mention of TargetPlatformVersion in neither project nor solution.

Comment: Is the ´<TargetFrameworkProfile>WindowsPhone71</TargetFrameworkProfile>´ correctly set?

Comment: It's a native project - there's no target framework. The closest I can find is `<PlatformToolset>v110_wp80</PlatformToolset>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It went away on its own after a few reopens and other meaningless actions. Ooky, spooky stuff. No idea why. SVN does not detect any changes to project files.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and the solution was to install the latest SDK for Windows Phone (SDK V8.0 at this time) in the computer (apparently it had a previous version version or not at all installed).

Answer (score 0):

```
Step1: Replace every occurrence of  $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) to 8.0 in your .vcxproj file
Step2: Restart Visual Studio

->Then You will get the error "The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found"

To fix this:
if you are using visual 2012 right click on project name -> properties -> configuration properties -> general -> platform toolset -> Visual Studio 2012 (v110) or wp-v110

And You will be good to go!

Note: You can then revert the changes from 8.0 to $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) in your project file if you want. (The cause of the error is when you open a vs2012 project or its dependencies in vs2013)
```